# Let a random experiment be the casting of a pair of fair six-sided dice and let X equal the minimum of the two outcomes .

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

the problem is I am suffering a lot in my journey,I cant even determine where I must start solve mathematical problems:

Let a random experiment be the casting of a pair
of fair six-sided dice and let X equal the minimum of the
two outcomes .

(a) With reasonable assumptions , find the pmf of X .

(c) Let Y equal the range of the two outcomes (i.e., the
absolute value of the difference of the largest and the
smallest outcomes). Determine the pmf g(y) of Y for
y = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Where must you start? You should start with the sample space. Are you able to write down a sample space?

Comment: There are $36$ equiprobable possible pairs $(i,j)$. Find out how many of them are favourable and apply the rule: probability is number of favourable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer :
sample space for each value and its repetition :

> $\{1: 11, 2: 9, 3: 7, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 1\}$
> and the $f(x) =(13-2x)/36$
> hope anyone looking for this problem, finds my solution helpful